# Will a Fermi Quadro graphics card support three independent monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, nvidia-quadro

I am interested in purchasing a Quadro 2000 graphics card, however, I know that the GeForce series will only do two monitors / card. But the Quadro cards have DisplayPort, which is a far easier signal to generate than TMDS (DVI-D), hence it's use on Radeon HD for more than three monitors. Can the Quadro cards with dual DisplayPort and DL DVI-I connectors can power three monitors via the two DP and DVI-D ports?

[image: NVIDIA Quadro 2000]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Lenovo](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/MIGR-76502.html) appears to be selling this card, have the following info posted:  It looks like only 2 ports work at a time.

Monitor Resolution Support:

```
* Two DisplayPort and one Dual-Link DVI-I
      o Only two of the three connectors are active at a time
      o 2560 x 1600 maximum digital resolution for DisplayPort and Dual-Link DVI-I connectors
      o 2048 x 1536 maximum analog resolution with the attached DVI-to-VGA monitor adapter to the Dual-Link DVI-I connector
      o 1920 x 1200 maximum digital resolution with an attached DisplayPort to Single-Link DVI-I Monitor cable (45J7915)
```

Comment: I haven't tested the Quadro 2000 specifically, but I believe this is correct. +1